# make qtip disappear right away

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, mouseover, qtip

so I want the following behavior out of qtip:

the qtip should show up when I click on the object (I got this working without problem)...but then I want to have it disappear after a few miliseconds without me having to do anything....how would you go about configuring qtip to do this?

i tried

```
hide: {
    when : 'inactive',
    delay : 100,
    fixed: false
}
```

but it's not working....

any help would be appreciated...thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want the tooltip to flash on screen:

```
$(".tooltip").qtip({
    content: "Test tooltip",
    api: {
        // As soon as the qtip is fully visible..
        onShow: function (event) {
            // Keep a reference to the qtip..
            that = this;
            // After 1ms (to let things settle down)
            setTimeout(function () {
                // Hide the qtip
                that.hide();
            }, 1); // change this value to have it stay on screen longer
        }
    },
    show: "mouseover"
});
```

Comment: should be $(that).hide();

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but just in case someone passes by, the right way to do it in qTip2 is: (events instead of api)

```
events: {
            show: function(event, api){
                var that = this;
                setTimeout(function () {
                   // Hide the qtip
                    that.hide();
                }, 3000); // change this value to have it stay on screen longer
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is correct, but the `delay` is causing problems.  100ms is only 0.1 seconds, so maybe the qtip is taking longer than that time to render, in which it won't exist yet when it's told to hide itself (just a guess).

I would increase the delay (you probably want your users to see the tip for a few seconds anyway) and see if that helps.  Here's an example that uses 1000ms: http://jsfiddle.net/andrewwhitaker/dVEYq/